# Dropup Menu not showing in Safari 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

If you view this url in FF, Chrome, and Opera you will see the menu slide out and at the bottom you will see a red dropup menu.

http://legacyballatlanta.com/dropupmenu/index.php

However in Safari 6 you will not see the menu.  This is driving me crazy.  When I take the menu out of the slide out div and place it below the slide out div, it shows in all browsers.  The slide out and the drop up menu is done via jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a `position: fixed` on your #nav element, change it to `position: absolute`. This will make the element dependent of the parent and behaves correctly on Safari.

```
#nav { bottom: 52px; width: 250px; position: absolute; }
```